# Physics2D.IgnoreCollision not work when rb not moving

Tags: unity

I want to use Physics2D.IgnoreCollision for ignoring collision between enemy and player, when player have shield.
But I have enemy who some time is static and some time jump only on y axis. When enemy not moving Physics2D.IgnoreCollision not work and physics collision between player and enemy occur even Physics2D.IgnoreCollision is called. When i add some velocity to enemy in update method
Code (CSharp):

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(0.1f, rb.velocity.y);
```

IgnoreCollision work like it should.

Can some one tell me why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible your body was sleeping at the time that you changed its collision state, and so its physics aren't simulated again until something wakes it up?

Comment: Im making every fame some game logic in update method, I don't think that body is sleeping

Comment: You "don't think"? [Did you check](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.IsAwake.html)?

Comment: I check now, when enemy is not moving isAwake is false, when enemy jump is Awake is true. Can you tell me in answer how to keep enemy wakeup ?     `rigidbody.sleepThreshold = 0.0f;`, on Update `rigidbody.WakeUp();` or another way ? I need this to all my enemies

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I try `if (rb.IsSleeping()) rb.WakeUp();` in Update but IgnoreCollison not work even `rb.isAwake` is true

Comment: I try changing in Inspector sleeping mode to never sleep and IgnoreCollison  not work again, only if I add some `rb.velocity` to enemy, IgnoreCollison   work

Comment: Show us the call to `IgnoreCollision()`, if code around has too many lines, at least tell where are you placing the call. Try moving It to `FixedUpdate()`.